# Is server fault an ok place for questions about citrix management?

Tags: discussion

I am a systems engineer that is currently learning about citrix in an MSP live production environment. I want to know if Server Fault is the place to go to ask questions regarding troubleshooting strange worker behaviours.

Answer (score 5):

Questions about *managing* Citrix environments are on-topic.  Bear in mind that diagnostic and troubleshooting questions need to be sufficiently detailed to enable others to reproduce the behaviour you're seeing.  A dump of random observations with "Any ideas?" at the bottom will not be received well.

Comment: Well then I have a tough one. I have citrix workers randomly rebooting, the admin panel registers the power on, but not the power up.

Comment: posted. we'll see how it goes. https://serverfault.com/questions/1008518/what-could-cause-xencenter-to-not-register-a-poweroff-in-the-vm-lifecycle-events

Comment: Yeeeeeeah, that's not a great question.  In my experience, with what you've got there, you'll either get no answers, or you'll get a half dozen "well it could be X" non-answers.  I've put the question on hold, and I'd suggest carefully reviewing the hold text, with particular attention to the "attempted solutions" -- as in, "what have you already looked at?".  If you edit your question, it'll automatically go into a review queue, so I (and many others) can reopen it once there's a decent chance it'll get useful answers.